# tkinter: Why aren't Combobox and Entry widgets deleted by delete("all")?

Tags: python, tkinter

I mean the whole widget not the text inside.
I also tried to get an existing solution on the forum.
I have stripped code to show the problem only.

My problem is...
When I place `ComboBox` and `Entry` widgets on `canvas2`, they don't get deleted with a `canvas2.delete("all")`.

The problem happens if you select "Weighted Graph", then "Undirected Graph" from the menu.
After "Weighted Graph", the `ComboBox` and `Entry` widgets ***remain*** (everything else gets deleted as expected).
I put in a time delay and some prompts to show the problem.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import time

tk = Tk()
tk.geometry("970x660")
menubar = Menu(tk)
tk.config(menu=menubar)

wrapper1 = LabelFrame(tk, text="Display", height=500)
wrapper2 = LabelFrame(tk, text="Command", width=800)

# canvas was setup to be a vertically scrolling region, I have cut most of that code
# (but my problem does not lie with canvas, that's working fine)
canvas = Canvas(wrapper1, height=500)
canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill="both", expand="yes")

myframe = Frame(canvas)
canvas.create_window((0,0), window=myframe, anchor="nw", height=500)

# Note: My problem lies on canvas2,
canvas2 = Canvas(wrapper2)
canvas2.pack(side=LEFT, fill="both", expand="yes")

canvas2.update()

wrapper1.pack(fill="both", expand="yes", padx=10, pady=0)
wrapper2.pack(fill="both", expand="yes", padx=10, pady=5)

def DoNothing():
    print("Doing nothing!")

def BinaryTree(Weighted, Mode):

    canvas.delete("all")
    print("Before canvas2.delete...")
    canvas2.delete("all")
    print("...after canvas2.delete... now waiting 3 seconds so you can inspect if canvas2 is CLEAR... ")
    print("...I would expect canvas2 to be clear but Combobox and Entry remain!... ")

    canvas2.update()
    tk.update()

    time.sleep(3)

    button1 = Button(canvas2, text = "Add Node",  command= lambda: DoNothing(), width=13, anchor=W)
    button1_window = canvas2.create_window(20, 40, anchor=W, window=button1)

    entry1 = Entry(canvas2, width=10)
    entry1.place(x=150, y=40, anchor=W)

    button2 = Button(canvas2, text = "Add Edge",  command= lambda: DoNothing(), width=13, anchor=W)
    button2_window = canvas2.create_window(20, 80, anchor=W, window=button2)

    cb1 = ttk.Combobox(canvas2, values=DoNothing(), postcommand=lambda: DoNothing(), width=13, state="readonly")
    cb1.place(x=150, y=80, anchor=W)

    cb2 = ttk.Combobox(canvas2, values=DoNothing(), postcommand=lambda: DoNothing(), width=13, state="readonly")
    cb2.place(x=260, y=80, anchor=W)

    if Weighted == True:
        canvas2.create_text(380, 80, text="Weight:", anchor=W)
        entry2 = Entry(canvas2, width=4)
        entry2.place(x=429, y=80, anchor=W)

    button3 = Button(canvas2, text = "Delete All Nodes",  command= lambda: DoNothing(), width=13, anchor=W)
    button3_window = canvas2.create_window(420, 40, anchor=W, window=button3)

    canvas2.update()
    tk.update()

lmenu = Menu(menubar)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Learning Menu", menu=lmenu)

lmenu.add_command(label="Weighted Graph", command= lambda: BinaryTree(True, "DirectedGraph"))
lmenu.add_command(label="Undirected Graph", command= lambda: BinaryTree(False, "UndirectedGraph"))


while True:
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why aren't Combobox and Entry widgets deleted by delete(“all”)?

That's just how tkinter is designed to work. The canvas `delete` method only deletes canvas objects. That means, objects created on the canvas with the "create" functions (`create_rectangle`, `create_window`, etc). For window objects, the `delete` method will delete the canvas object created with `create_window` but it's not designed to delete the widget associated with that window object.

Like with any widget, to delete the actual widget you need to call the `destroy` method on the widget itself.

> My problem is... When I place ComboBox and Entry widgets on canvas2, they don't get deleted with a canvas2.delete("all").

That is because when you use `place`, you are not creating canvas objects. For the `delete` command to work, you must call `create_window` for the combox and entry widgets.

Comment: I used canvas2.create_window(429, 80, anchor=W, window=entry2) works as I wanted :)

Comment: Bryan: I find it strange that you didn't mention that when `Canvas.delete()` is passed a string, it interprets it as a tag and deletes all `Canvas` objects with that have that tag — but there aren't any.

Comment: @martineau: "all" is a special tag that is known by the `delete` method (and other methods). It doesn't require that items literally have the tag "all".

Comment: Bryan: Oh…dare I ask if these special `Canvas` tags are documented anywhere (or covered in a tkinter tutorial)?

Comment: @martineau: yes, they are documented in the official tk documentation here: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/canvas.htm. As for tutorials, I'm not deeply familiar with an tkinter tutorials, but the one at [tkdocs.com](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/canvas.html) shows the use of 'all' in a couple of examples. For me, the definitive source for documentation is always the tcl/tk man pages. They are very thorough.

Answer (score 0):

To destroy a widget in tkinter try .destroy()

```
f1=tk.Frame()
f1.destroy()
```